# What does it mean by saying, 'the functions are preserved by analytic change of variables' in a analytic manifold...

Tags: manifolds, analytic-geometry, analytic-functions

What does it mean by saying, 'the  functions are preserved by analytic change of variables'  in a compact analytic manifold

Comment: I suppose that it means that the function of change of variable must be analytic.

Comment: I dont think so...